# Code::Blocks writing code in other language

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

is there any change to write code for Code::Blocks in **other language** as English, in particular Greek language ( or other ) and i mean to write real code-lines in e.g. in C or C++ with Greek letters and those being understand as real code.

Comment: Please don't write non-english code ever!

Comment: If you use a proper character set, you can write comments and string literals in native language. The C syntax is english, though and you should not use non-ASCII identifiers. Note that source and target character set of the compiler are properly set. But note that you will hardly get support from an internation community like SO for such code.

Comment: @PeterVaro: Why should he not write in his native language like English speakers, too?

Comment: How would you write e.g. `while` in non-latin characters?

Comment: Also, read about [the phases of translation for C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), especially about phase 1 which is about the characters supported.

Comment: @Olaf have you ever worked with non-english code? I'm hungarian (ofc speaking hungarian), I've learnt french, latin and english -- but still, non-english code is just a pain in the arse!

Comment: @PeterVaro: I do not talk about the code as such, but the comments and string literals (which actually have to be). I write english myself, but have well-worked with non-english code (i.e. comments/string literals; I agree it is a bad idea to use non-english keywords (how?), though). I just don't see it that dogmatic. OP must be aware there will be likely no support in an international community, of course.

Comment: @Olaf string literals are okay for me (though I prefer escape sequences there too) -- but comments(?!), they should be very important parts of a code base, which helps you understand all the magic happening in the code (or explaining the attemp the given snippet should do), so non-english code will definitely kill the ability of collaboration

Comment: @PeterVaro: Why escape-sequences? Just configure a proper source and target character set in your compiler (gcc e.g. uses UTF-8 by default for both). Did you ever program embedded devices? There you have to care about such subjects anyway. And, yes, why not native language if you e.g. code for/with kids which might not be that safe in English? (Note that I code myself all-English, though - unless explicitly required otherwise by a customer.) There is still enough non-international collabration and English is (very likely) not the most spoken language in the world.

Answer (score 0):

You should not writte non-english code. Most compiler semantics are all configured expecting both a encode for letters/commands as well as a "way of thinking", that is english-like oriented.

Even arabic programmers, cyriliac programmers and latin programmers all writte in english-like commands, and expect a defined boolean logic set of operations to compile code.... However, if what you want is "readable-code", then use the comment system to detail what is to be done within the code

Comment: they do exist several ID E's in Greek language who allow Greek letters as code to be written. there is in particular  a version of DEV++ witch allows to write Greek code and there is a famous here in Greece IDE called " Glossomatheia" witch is full Greek (IDE & Code-writing) . Mr Pileborg  asked... " while" in non-latin characters => ΟΣΟ, loop  => ΕΠΑΝΑΛΑΒΕ,  end_if => ΤΕΛΟΣ_ΑΝ...and many more!

Comment: I understand that there are IDEs specific for different languages, I myself am a brazzilian speaking person. But, as far as programs go, its best that people understand the basic operators/commands of a supported IDE, and use them. You are way more likely to get help from others/Internet if you have a english-like code, than not having it... Chinese/Japanese/Korean keep on asking this forum for help, and they get it... but when it is not in UTF-8 or close characters, people cant even try to aid.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from a non-native English, from a country that uses weird non-standard letters.

First of all, you should never include any non-standard characters in your source code as that might give you compiler errors. Standard in this case is any character appearing either in classic 7-bit ASCII or perhaps in UTF-8.

You should not name any identifiers in your native language, nor should you write any comments in your native language. Consider this:

- What if the code is to be maintained/used by someone who doesn't know your language?

  If you write in your native language, you severely restrict which developers that will be able to work with the code. Meaning in your case, your company could only recruit programmers who know Greek, and your company would not be able to sell the source code outside Greece. Why reduce your market to just one country?
- What if you need help/support from someone? Either through formal support channels or through informal ones (like SO). They will expect you to show code in English, or otherwise you are on your own. So by writing in your native language, you have severely reduced your chances of getting help with your source code, or anything related to it, such as libraries and hardware interacting with your code.
- Why would you want to learn all programming terms in multiple languages? C, C++ and all other languages uses English words as part of the language itself. There is no getting around learning the English terms.

  I remember this being a pain when I studied programming and the classes were in my native language: not only did I have to learn each term in English, I also had to learn it in my native language. Meaning I had to learn twice as many strange technical terms. And half of them I will never use, since all programmers use English anyhow.
- To be able to function at all as a programmer, you must know English. All manuals/books, all support channels, the language itself, will be in English. So either you already know English sufficiently, or you need to learn it. Otherwise you cannot work effectively as a professional programmer.

So if you think of it, there is not much to gain by using your native language, but a whole lot to lose. Also, such programs tend to end up as a messy mix between English and the native language anyhow.

Comment: although this is not the kind of answer i was expecting it helps though others too understand that once in English always in English! or you (me, everyone) sits down and translates the whole IDE to his likes! i think this answer is by this meaning USEFUL! thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

in `DEV++` for Greek Language
Press :

*Tools* -> *compilers options* -> *General(type (-finput-charset=cp1253-fexec-charset=cp737)*